# PHP: echo selected value from a drop down list

Tags: php, html, sql

I have this drop-down list that I created using one of MySQL table. The drop-down list is working fine but for some reason I am not able to echo the selected value here is my code:

```
<?php
      require_once('config.php');
      // CONNECT
       mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
       mysql_select_db('Database');

 ?>
 // other.php is another php file
 <form action="other.php" method="POST">

            <label>Quantity:</label>
            <input type="number" min="1" name="quantity" value="1"/>
            <br/>
            <hr/>

            <?php
                    echo makeFormEntry('Product Type', 'type', $types);
                    echo makeFormEntry('Product Occasion', 'occasion', $occasions);
                    echo makeFormEntry('Product Size', 'size', $sizes);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM Table";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            echo "<b>Name : </b>" . "<select id='Name' name='Name'>";
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
             echo "<option value='" . $row['Name'] . "'>" . $row['Name'] . "</option>";
            }
                    echo "</select><br>";
               echo "<input type='submit'/><input type='reset'/>";
  ?>
  </form>
```

here is what I have tried:

```
  $n=$_POST['Name'];
   echo $n;
```

Comment: `echo "<option ".($_POST['Name']==$row['Name']?'selected':'')." value=`

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE"; What table? is that the name of your table? Do you have your form name stored in the database?

Comment: Yes its the table name just for illustration

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions I am not getting you.

Comment: mmmh ok, can i ask this: Does your form use method `POST` or `GET`. And better do a `var_dump($_POST)` to see what was posted. And my first comment (when everthing else is working) will pre-select the value in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

The drop down list must be contained in a form. You can't get a value from the `$_POST` array if it isn't set submitting a form.
You should use this code :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "Options" . "<form method='post'><select id='name' name='name'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo "<option value='" . $row['Name'] . "'>" . $row['Name'] . "
     </option>";
}
echo "</select><input type='submit' name='submit'></form><br>";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo $_POST['name'];
}
```

I hope this is going to help you!

Comment: My code is in form, still not working I dont know why

Comment: @J.Doe Can you include the entire script?

Comment: This line : echo "</select><input type='submit' name='submit'><form method='post'><br>";  is wrong

Comment: you should rather use this one : echo "</select><input type='submit' name='submit'></form><br>";

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
  echo "<option if($row["Name"]=="Doe") ? "selected='selected'":"" value='".$row['Name']."'>".$row["Name"]."</option>";
```

Comment: select always all options?

Comment: Where should I insert this script I inserted it my page stopped working

Comment: getting a blank screen

Comment: Replace this echo "<option value='" . $row['Name'] . "'>" . $row['Name'] . "</option>"  with above code and remove <br> in  echo "</select><br>";